# How to add android to cordova platform - PATH error?

Tags: cordova-3

Please help me with this issue!

Error: Failed to run "android". Make sure you have the latest Android SDK instal
led, and that the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your
PATH.

Thanks.

see http://eosvn.com/images/Screenshot%202014-10-02%2011.39.00.png

Comment: PATH = C:\Users\tai\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;D:\Android\adt-x64\sdk\platform-tools;D:\Android\adt-x64\sdk\tools;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin

Comment: better to edit your question, not to add such unreadable comments